# Could reincarnation entail something like Star Trek's "symbiont"?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction

The mind-body connection could lead us to conclude that both the mind and the body, inter-connected, might contain past life memories. Under hypnosis and even not under hypnosis, many people have seemed to remember past lives. This question presupposes that the reader does believe in reincarnation.  If we strongly feel in our gut and in our brain that there is a connection with somebody or somebodies in the past, the whole body will feel this.  The notion of the symbiont is an actual entity that passes through one life to the next, perhaps an entity that is in essence ethereal but becomes physical again and again.

Comment: Considering reincarnation isn't real, we can't really comment on how it would work unless you state so explicitly. The mind isn't a thing, it's a set of faculties that are invoked by a part of the body, the brain. In Humans, memories are explicitly contained in the cells of the brain. If you want an external organism to give off memories, it would have to create pathways of axonal fibres to parts of the brain that invoke memories.

Comment: @Feyre Essentially the question is asking if a 'Star Trek" symbiont existed, could this be the basis for a form of reincarnation. This is basic worldbuilding for a world where a specific kind of reincarnation is part of the furniture. I'm not familiar with the symbiont in question. Others may be. Although I do share your ideas about memory and the brain.

Comment: @a4android Which is why I asked for guidelines. As I understand it, the Trill symbiont just send "electrical signals", and that the Trill themselves have some psychic capabilities. The question doesn't state if that kind of hand-wavy explanation is enough, but at that point you can just make up anything, as the OP has already done herself.

Comment: @Feyre That's reasonable. I understand where you're coming from now. We need guidance from RuthCampbell about her concept of reincarnation to work out its parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the Hindu/Buddhist theory of reincarnation. We have seven bodies of increasing subtlety - physical (manomayakosa, body made of food), energy (pranamayakosa, body made of prana/bioenergy), astral/emotional (manomayakosa, body made of the lower/animal mind), mental (vijanamayakosa, body made of the higher mind), causal (anandamayakosa, body made of bliss), spiritual (the buddhi body), and universal (at this level we are all one, body made of everything).

When we die, only the first two bodies die. The other five continue, spend some time on the astral plane (where there are Hellish and Heavenly areas), and eventually return to inhabit a new physical/energetic body system.

If you want to use this model, maybe do some research into Tibetan Buddhism or traditional Vedic metaphysics, and then create a device that can measure, maybe even direct the "soul" - the five more subtle bodies.

(Technically, of course, you can only work with four subtle bodies, because at the level of the seventh body, we are all part of one being.)